# Parsing linear equation with Parameters using REGEX

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the linear equation using REGEX. Equation looks as follow:

```
2 * var1.val          + 7 * var2 + 9 * var3 = 1
3 * var1.val          + 4 * var2            = 9
param1.val * var1.val            + 4 * var3 = 7
```

The coefficients can be numeric or parameters. I want to get result as:

```
[2,         7,  9
3,          4,  0
param1.val, 0,  4]
```

I googled and found a sample code which I modified to meet my need. It looks like:

```
equations = [' 2 * var1.name + 7 * var2 + 9 * var3 = 1',
             ' 3 * var1.name + 4 * var2 = 9',
             ' param1.val * var1.name + 4 * var3 = 7']
augmented_matrix = {'__b__':[0]*3}                 # initialize the RHS vector
parse_ptrn = r'([+-]?[\d*|\w*][\*]+)(\w+\.?\w+)'        
parse_obj = re.compile(parse_ptrn)

for i in range(3):
    e = ''.join(equations[i].split())              # split and join to remove spaces
    left, right = e.split('=')                     # separate RHS and LHS

    try:
        augmented_matrix['__b__'][i] = float(right) # if possible convert RHS to float
    except:
        augmented_matrix['__b__'][i] = right
    # FOR LHS
    for coeff, var in parse_obj.findall(left):
        if coeff == '': coeff = 1
        elif coeff == '-': coeff = -1
        else:
            try:
                coeff = float(coeff.replace("*","")) # convert to float/Remove * from coeff
            except:
                coeff = coeff.replace("*","")
        if var not in augmented_matrix:
            augmented_matrix[var] = [0] * 3 
        augmented_matrix[var][i] = coeff
    print left, right
    print parse_obj.findall(left)
```

It is not able correctly parse the third equation because of the parameters. For first coefficient in third equation, it gives me last letter "l" instead of "param.val". I believe REGEX  **([+-]?[\d*|\w*][\*]+)**  should be able to find anything between start of the string and * (either digit or characters).

Please help me.

Comment: Are you basing this on fixed field position ? Otherwise, how do you get those `0`'s ?

Comment: the default value for the coefficient is 0 (initialized as list of zeros). so if no coefficient is found for the variable, it will have 0 coefficient.

Comment: Somehow the previous comment disappeared. but taking hint from it, I modified the REGEX to **([+-]?[\d*\w*\.]*[\*]+)(\w+\.?\w+)**  and it works. The reason it didn't worked is that I was assuming that the parameter can be either digital or string but, in this case, it is combination. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the reason that fixed it is because of the `*` you added after the `[\d*\w*\.]`. See my answer below for a full explanation. Also, I would recommend reading up on what square brackets `[]` mean in regular expressions, because your use of `*` (and `|` in your original code) within them is not correct, and `[*]` is essentially the same as `\*`, but less readable in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your regular expression instead:

```
parse_ptrn = r'([+-]?[\w.]*\*)(\w+\.?\w+)'
```

I changed `[\d*|\w*]` (i.e., ONE character which is a digit `\d`, asterisk `*`, pipe `|` or word character `\w`) to `[\w.]+` (i.e., AT LEAST ONE word character or decimal point). Note that `\d` is not necessary because it is a subset of `\w` (all digits are word characters). Also, your original code would not have worked for multi-digit coefficients, like `10`, because it was only selecting ONE character before the `*`.

Please note that this will still not work for equations like `var1.val + 4 * var2 = 9` due to the lack of coefficient and `*` in front of the first variable, `var1.val`. I will leave this as an exercise for you, but if you have trouble with it, just comment on this answer and I will update it to include that case as well (I assume you would want a coefficient of `1` in that case)?

Comment: Now I understand [] and \w correctly. I changed your answer to r'([+-]?[\w.]*\\*)?(\w+\.?\w+)' and it works equation var1.val + 4 * var2 = 9 too. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, one additional modification. You will want to add the `?` after the `\*` instead (not after the `)`) because that regex will not work for equations like `-var1.val + 4 * var2 = 9` due to the lack of `*` but the existence of `-`. So the regex should be `r'([+-]?[\w.]*\*?)(\w+\.?\w+)'`

Comment: Even the regular expression you gave doesn't work on `-var1.val + 4 * var2 = 9`. I believe it's because there is no way re will know where to split `-var1.val` so it splits it in `-var1.v` and `al` Do you think, I need if else loop to accomplish it?

Comment: No, try this instead: `r'([+-]?(?:[\w.]+\*)?)(\w+\.?\w+)'`

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, if you know the order of the equations (like 3), it is
possible to do it all in a single regex.

```
 # ^(?=.*?\S+\s*\*\s*var[123]).*?(?:(\S+)\s*\*\s*var1.+?)?(?:(\S+)\s*\*\s*var2.+?)?(?:(\S+)\s*\*\s*var3.+?)?$

 ^ 
 (?=
      .*? \S+ 
      \s* \* \s* var [123] 
 )
 .*? 
 (?:
      ( \S+ )                       # (1)
      \s* \* \s* var1
      .+? 
 )?
 (?:
      ( \S+ )                       # (2)
      \s* \* \s* var2
      .+? 
 )?
 (?:
      ( \S+ )                       # (3)
      \s* \* \s* var3
      .+? 
 )?
 $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 47 ) 
2 * var1.val          + 7 * var2 + 9 * var3 = 1  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
2  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 24 , len 1 ) 
7  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 35 , len 1 ) 
9  
-------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 49 , len 47 ) 
3 * var1.val          + 4 * var2            = 9  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 49 , len 1 ) 
3  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 73 , len 1 ) 
4  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
-------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 98 , len 47 ) 
param1.val * var1.val            + 4 * var3 = 7  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 98 , len 10 ) 
param1.val  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 133 , len 1 ) 
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It definitely works for the example I gave. I am going to use the REGEX for large system of equation with unknown number of equations, variables and parameters.

Comment: @rahulchem - If you think of regex as using all available LIBC functions on the assembly  level, you might think that if you can't define what you're doing with regex, .. it _can't_be done on the language level. So this `large system of equation with unknown number of ..., variables and parameters` with all those unknowns, isn't going to work at any level.

Comment: I am forcing user to do it a way that it works. but i agree that can't do everything using regex.